# Where can I find the Release Schedule for CiviCRM?

Tags: release

I know there are regular releases of new versions, but when are they?

Answer (score 3):

Releases are generally the first Wednesday of each month.

The testing period for the next release starts when the current release is published.

The [release dates and testing periods](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/release/blob/master/README.md) are recorded in gitlab